# Capture RGB from Kinnect with Openni and show with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, kinect, rgb, simple-openni

I need to capture the color RGB image from a Kinnect camera, but I want to show it in OpenCV as this is only a part of a bigger program. I know OpenCV has compatibility with OpenNI if you set the flag, but although I tried hard CMake couldn't find the path to OpenNI2 so I couldn't build OpenCV with OpenNI. Anyway I think it is good to know how to manually convert OpenNI frames to openCV frames, so I decided to follow this way.

For capturing the color frame in OpenNI I tried the following:

```
openni::Device device;  
openni::VideoStream  color;
openni::VideoFrameRef colorFrame;

rc = openni::OpenNI::initialize();
rc = device.open(openni::ANY_DEVICE);
rc = color.create(device, openni::SENSOR_COLOR);
rc = color.start();

color.readFrame(&colorFrame);
const openni::RGB888Pixel* imageBuffer = (const openni::RGB888Pixel*)colorFrame.getData();
```

But now I don't understand how to do the conversion to cv::Mat.

Does any anybody manged to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, first you should separate initialization from the loop for reading frames, this way.

**Initialization**

```
openni::Device device;  
openni::VideoStream  color;
openni::VideoFrameRef colorFrame;

rc = openni::OpenNI::initialize();
rc = device.open(openni::ANY_DEVICE);
rc = color.create(device, openni::SENSOR_COLOR);
rc = color.start();

Mat frame;
```

Now comes the main loop for reading frames. You have done almost everything, the only thing left is to copy the buffer to the openCV Mat.

**Loop for reading frames**

```
while (true)
{
   color.readFrame(&colorFrame);
   const openni::RGB888Pixel* imageBuffer = (const openni::RGB888Pixel*)colorFrame.getData();

   frame.create(colorFrame.getHeight(), colorFrame.getWidth(), CV_8UC3);
   memcpy( frame.data, imageBuffer, 3*colorFrame.getHeight()*colorFrame.getWidth()*sizeof(uint8_t) );

   cv::cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2RGB); //this will put colors right
}
```

Comment: how to do the same for the depth image ? I can't figure out how to change the CV_8U3...etc.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @Jav_Rock's answer above, for IR and Depth the solution is similar, except for the following (in place of `SENSOR_COLOR`, `CV_8UC3` and `RGB888Pixel`, respectively):

**Depth**

- Sensor type: `SENSOR_DEPTH`
- OpenCV type: `CV_16UC1`
- VideoFrameRef data: `DepthPixel`

Note you'll probably want to set the PixelMode for the VideoStream's VideoFormat to `PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_100_UM` otherwise your depth image will look very black.

**IR**

- Sensor type: `SENSOR_IR`
- OpenCV type: `CV_16UC1`
- VideoFrameRef data: `Grayscale16Pixel`

Finally, note that neither depth nor IR need the `cv::cvtColor` call.